# Set cookie with JavaScript does not work for Safari on OS X

Tags: javascript, cookies

Somehow safari will not save a cookie via JavaScript, but chrome and others work as expected.

```
// save screen width in cookie to get more results on searches for highres
document.cookie = "sw="+($(window).width());
```

How can I save a cookie with safari browsers in JavaScript?

Comment: By doing that. So something else is at play.

Comment: You are right, works in anonymous mode of safari. Closed and reopened, but still no effect just in anonymous mode. The oposite one might expect.

Comment: So something else is at play--it works fine for me (and I'd be surprised if it didn't work under essentially any version of Safari/OS X since it's how the web works).